# Unable to download maven dependencies in intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

When I try to download maven dependencies using **mvn clean install** in intellij
facing this issue.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project IAPORTAL: Could not resolve dependencies for project SAMPLE:SAMPLE:war:${bambooBuildNumber}: Failed to collect dependencies at or
g.drools:drools-compiler:jar:6.0.1.Final: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.drools:drools-compiler:jar:6.0.1.Final: Could not transfer artifact org.jboss.dashboard-bu
ilder:dashboard-builder-bom:pom:6.0.1.Final from/to mvn repository (https://mvnrepository.com/): authorization failed for https://mvnrepository.com/org/jboss/dashboard-builder/dashboard-builder-bom/6.0.1.Final/dashboard-builder-bom-6.0.1.Final.pom, status: 403 Forbidden -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

How can we resolve this?

Comment: Don't post text (code, errors, etc.) as images. Just post the text please.

Comment: This `https://mvnrepository.com/` is not a consumable repository. You should use the defaults.... Please show your pom file..

Answer (score 0):

Your dependency seems to be wrong.

Check out https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.dashboard-builder/dashboard-builder-bom/6.0.1.Final to see how to properly set your dependency.

Your pom should contain this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.dashboard-builder</groupId>
    <artifactId>dashboard-builder-bom</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.1.Final</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```